# How to get the hive partition column name using spark

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I have a table in hive whose DDL looks like this.

CREATE TABLE ABC(
  `name` string)
PARTITIONED BY (
  `col1` string,
  `col2` bigint,
  `col3` string,
  `col4` string)

I have a requirement in which I have to store the non partition column name of hive table into variable1 and partition column name into variable2 using spark scala.

Desired output would be :

```
 variable1='name'    

 variable2='col1,col2,col3,col4'
```

I am following the below approach but not able to get the same.

```
val df=sql("desc default.ABC")

val df2=df.map(r => r.getString(0)).collect.toList

List[String] = List(name, col1, col2, col3, col4, # Partition Information, # col_name, col1, col2, col3, col4)
```

Can you please help me with the approach?

Answer (score 3):

try this :

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val partitionsColumns = spark.catalog.listColumns("wikicc").where(col("ispartition") === true).select("name").collect().map(_.getAs[String]("name"))
val noParitionsColumns = spark.catalog.listColumns("wikicc").where(col("ispartition") === false).select("name").collect().map(_.getAs[String]("name"))
println(partitionsColumns.mkString(","))
println(noParitionsColumns.mkString(","))
```

Comment: In pyspark one can do this: `partitions_columns = [col.name for col in spark.catalog.listColumns("schema_name.table_name") if col.isPartition]` and `non_paritions_columns =  [col.name for col in spark.catalog.listColumns("schema_name.table_name") if not col.isPartition]`

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
val df=sql("show partitions default.ABC")
```

you can get 'partition' column. then collect get you want.

If you want create table partition,you can use spark-sql execute

```
show create table tableName
```

you can get 'createtab_stmt' column of Dataset.

Comment: It can solve problems, but  it''s not elegant operation;